# Vim Latex spellcheck accents (\ ')

Tags: vim-latex

I'm using vim and latex for my proyecs. In general I use English and Spanish. My problem is that in Spanish there are a lot of accents and for a "security" thing I prefer (and it's request in were I work) to write them using '.
How can I make that the spellchecker see like good this form of accent and not the conventional.
Example: á wrong, \ ' a good.

And how can I make that the suggestions of corrections also respect this convention?

The way i use spell check is like this:

```
:setlocal spell! spelllang=es
```

Comment: There's no problem in using accented letters, nowadays.

Comment: I know, but were I work it's a need too put things like that. Thas why I'm trying to have this corrections convention.